# vue - remove latest child path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

so I currently have my router paths set up as such:

```
{
    component: List,
    name: "account-list",
    path: "list/:id",
    // alias: "list/:id/edit_item/:item_id",
    children: [
        {
            path: "edit_item/:item_id",
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            redirect: "/account/list/:id"
        }
    ]
}
```

And let's say we have a url like this: `http://localhost:8080/#/account/list/5bb17bdec7fb946609ce8bd4/edit_item/5bbc2d12aded99b39c9eadb9`

How would I turn this into:

`http://localhost:8080/#/account/list/5bb17bdec7fb946609ce8bd4`

I am currently using

```
this.$router.back()
```

Which generally works well, but if I were to have accessed another item by directly pasting in its url, `this.$router.back()` would just revisit the previous url.

So is there a surefire way to guarantee that I would remove the child path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue router will maintain current params when navigating so you should be able to navigate to the named parent route.

For example

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'account-list' })
```

The current `:id` param will be re-used.

If you wanted to make it dynamic, you could work your way up the current route's `matched` array. For example, to go to the current route's named parent

```
this.$router.push({
  name: this.$route.matched[this.$route.matched.length - 2].name 
})
```

This will only work on nested routes of course as the `matched` length for top-level routes is only 1.

---

For non-named routes you must construct the full path with all params interpolated into the string. You could do it by getting the destination routes `path` property and substituting param tokens with those in `this.$route.params` but that's going to get messy. Eg

```
// get parent path property
let path = this.$route.matched[this.$route.matched.length - 2].path
let realPath = path.replace(/:\w+/g, param => 
    this.$route.params[param.substr(1)])
this.$router.push(realPath)
```

This won't work if your paths use advanced pattern matching.

Comment: so in the event I do not have a named route there's no way to get a guarantee?

Comment: Named routes certainly make it easier

Comment: Yeah they do, I'm just covering all my bases.

Comment: @A.Lau I've added a somewhat hacky solution for non-named routes

Comment: yeah i was thinking I would have to do some string place if I really wanted to do it without named routes.

Answer (score 3):

You can move your child route up one level, so that it is not a child anymore. That way the `id` would show up in the `this.$router.params` object.

```
[
  {
    path: 'list/:id',
    component: List,
    name: "account-list"
  },
  {
    path: 'list/:id/edit_item/:itemid',
    component: Form,
    name: "account-form"
  }
]
```

You can do a do a `$router.replace` to replace the current path.

```
const id = this.$router.params['id'];

this.$router.replace({
  name: 'account-form',
  params: { id }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your list id `5bb17bdec7fb946609ce8bd4` in **localStorage** and get that localStorage in route script file.And add it your redirect path. For ex:

```
var listId = localStorage.getItem('listId');
// routh obj
{
    component: List,
    name: "account-list",
    path: "list/:id",
    // alias: "list/:id/edit_item/:item_id",
    children: [
        {
            path: "edit_item/:item_id",
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            redirect: "/account/list/" + listId
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the list's id first before replacing the route.

```
let currentId = this.$route.params.id
this.$router.replace({
  name: 'list',
  params: { id: currentId }
})
```

also, it would be better if you name your sub routes.